# replace image in header, OpenXML

Tags: c#, replace, openxml

I am hoping that someone can assist with this issue. I am using OpenXMl to search and replace for text in the header, body and footer of a word document using Open XML. The text is working fine. But the image is not replacing as I would expect it to. The image (@"C:\temp\pic\Logo.gif") does exist at the source. But never shows up in the word document correctly. You can see in the region below (#region "Modify Header Logo")
Can anyone assist? Thank you!

[Word Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG9eF.png)

```
       public void SearchAndReplace(string templateFileNameTemplate, string targetFileName, ProjectModel project)
    {

        //copy template file
        if (File.Exists(targetFileName) == true)
        {
            File.Delete(targetFileName);
        }

        File.Copy(templateFileNameTemplate, targetFileName);

        string searchText = "", replaceText = "", headerLogo = "", headerText = "";
        bool replace = false;

        //open file
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFileName, true))
        {

            //Gets all the headers
            foreach (var headerPart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
            {
                //Gets the text in headers
                foreach (var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Text>())
                {
                    replace = false;

                    switch (currentText.Text)
                    {
                        case "<COMPANY NAME>":
                            replace = true;
                            replaceText = project.ClientName;
                            searchText = currentText.Text;
                            break;
                        **case "<INSERT YOUR LOGO HERE>":
                            headerLogo = @"C:\temp\pic\Logo.gif";//project.ClientLogo;**
                            headerText = currentText.Text;
                            break;
                        case "<ISSUE DATE>":
                            replace = true;
                            replaceText = project.AssignedDate.ToShortDateString();
                            searchText = currentText.Text;
                            break;
                        case "<REVIEW DATE>":
                            replace = true;
                            replaceText = project.ClientDueDate.ToShortDateString();
                            searchText = currentText.Text;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    if(searchText.Length>0 && replace==true)
                        currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace(searchText, replaceText);
                }
            }
            //Gets all the footers
            foreach (var footerPart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts)
            {
                //Gets the text in headers
                foreach (var currentText in footerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Text>())
                {
                    replace = false;
                    switch (currentText.Text)
                    {
                        case "<COMPANY NAME>":
                            replace = true;
                            replaceText = project.ClientName;
                            searchText = currentText.Text;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    if (searchText.Length > 0 && replace == true)
                        currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace(searchText, replaceText);
                }
            }
            #region "Modify Header Logo"
            if(headerLogo != string.Empty)
            {
                ImagePart imagePart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(headerLogo, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
                }
                searchText = headerText;
                Text textPlaceHolder = null;
                // Insert image (the image created with your function) after text place holder.        
                // Search for text holder
                //Gets all the headers
                foreach (var headerPart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
                {
                    //Gets the text in headers
                    foreach (var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
                    {
                        textPlaceHolder = headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Text>()
                            .Where((x) => x.Text == searchText).First();
                    }
                }


                if (textPlaceHolder != null)
                {
                    var parent = textPlaceHolder.Parent;

                    if (parent is Run)  // Parent should be a run element.
                    {
                        //add image
                        Drawing imageElement = GetImageElement(
                            wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart),
                            headerLogo,
                            "my image",
                            475,
                            245);
                        // Insert image (the image created with your function) after text place holder.        
                        textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter<Drawing>(imageElement, textPlaceHolder);
                        // Remove text place holder.
                        textPlaceHolder.Remove();
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Regex regexText = new Regex("&lt;COMPANY NAME&gt;");
            docText = regexText.Replace(docText, project.ClientName);

            //regexText = new Regex("&lt;COMPANY NAME&gt;");
            //docText = regexText.Replace(docText, project.ClientName);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }

            //wordDoc.SaveAs(targetFileName).Close();
        }
    }

        private static Drawing GetImageElement(
        string imagePartId,
        string fileName,
        string pictureName,
        double width,
        double height)
    {
        double englishMetricUnitsPerInch = 914400;
        double pixelsPerInch = 96;

        //calculate size in emu
        double emuWidth = width * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;
        double emuHeight = height * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;

        var element = new Drawing(
            new A.Wordprocessing.Inline(
                new A.Wordprocessing.Extent { Cx = (Int64Value)emuWidth, Cy = (Int64Value)emuHeight },
                new A.Wordprocessing.EffectExtent { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
                new A.Wordprocessing.DocProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = pictureName },
                new A.Wordprocessing.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                new A.GraphicFrameLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                new A.Graphic(
                    new A.GraphicData(
                        new A.Pictures.Picture(
                            new A.Pictures.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                new A.Pictures.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = fileName },
                                new A.Pictures.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                            new A.Pictures.BlipFill(
                                new A.Blip(
                                    new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new A.BlipExtension { Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" }))
                                {
                                    Embed = imagePartId,
                                    CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                        new A.Stretch(new A.FillRectangle())),
                            new A.Pictures.ShapeProperties(
                                new A.Transform2D(
                                    new A.Offset { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                    new A.Extents { Cx = (Int64Value)emuWidth, Cy = (Int64Value)emuHeight }),
                                new A.PresetGeometry(
                                    new A.AdjustValueList())
                                { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle })))
                    {
                        Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
                    }))
            {
                DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                EditId = "50D07946"
            });
        return element;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, here's the markup for an image (Picture.png) that I manually inserted in a Word document. Did you check the markup created by your code against markup created by Microsoft Word when inserting the same image manually? This often helps spot errors in the markup (not always, though, because there are multiple "ways to Rome" and the same thing can often be expressed in multiple ways). You could use the Open XML Productivity Tool to compare the two documents, for example, and look at the differences in markup and the code required to create the correct markup.

```xml
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:drawing>
        <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="787F9556" wp14:editId="6F9F029A">
          <wp:extent cx="4026107" cy="4019757"/>
          <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
          <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 2" descr="A close up of a sign&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
          <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
          </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
          <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
              <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:cNvPr id="2" name="Picture.png"/>
                  <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                </pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:blipFill>
                  <a:blip r:embed="rId1">
                    <a:extLst>
                      <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                        <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                      </a:ext>
                    </a:extLst>
                  </a:blip>
                  <a:stretch>
                    <a:fillRect/>
                  </a:stretch>
                </pic:blipFill>
                <pic:spPr>
                  <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:ext cx="4026107" cy="4019757"/>
                  </a:xfrm>
                  <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                    <a:avLst/>
                  </a:prstGeom>
                </pic:spPr>
              </pic:pic>
            </a:graphicData>
          </a:graphic>
        </wp:inline>
      </w:drawing>
    </w:r>
```

Secondly, the following code does not make a lot of sense, because you don't need the `foreach` loop. That loop takes all `w:t` descendants of `w:hdr` but never uses `currentText` in the body of the loop.

```cs
foreach (var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
{
    textPlaceHolder = headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Text>()
       .Where((x) => x.Text == searchText).First();
}
```

The body of the loop is sufficient. I'd just use `FirstOrDefault` and check for null, unless you are 100% sure that the text will exist in all (!) headers.

Comment: I checked the data as you suggested and found that the reference to the image had the full path of the image (C:\Users\MyUser\Projects\MyProject\API\wwwroot\images\ImageName.gif), while one I put in manually only has the image name itself...I am going to work from there, but any clue as to why that might be?

Comment: @HAC Inspect the original file: Is the logo linked back to its original file? Word can store a graphic totally within a file, or linked to a file, or both. When there's a link to a file, if the file content would change (same file path and name, but different picture) the picture shown in the document would change. As far as I know, that's when a full path will be stored in the document.

Comment: This was the issue...
ImagePart imagePart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

This line specifies the MainDocumentPart, while I was trying to change it in the header...stupid mistake

Comment: Did you use the Productivity Tool as suggested to identify this? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Your answer was helpful in that it showed me a new tool. It did not assist with identifying the issue.